# Calculate score according to another indexed field‏?

Tags: solr, solrnet

My schema is like below

```
<fields>   
    <field name="ProductId" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />    
    <field name="ProductName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="ProductDesription" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="ProductRating" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
</fields>
```

Product name will be passed as q parameter to solr.
Is there a way to affect score on the basis of "ProductRating" which is not passed as query parameter ?

Or I need to go to solr source code and change the ranking algorithm ?

Please Guide me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by `ProductRating`, then simply append another query param like this:
`q=ProductName:book&sort=ProductRating desc` or you can use `ProductRating` in a [function query](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) to influence the score.

Answer (score 0):

You can boost the results on the basis of the product rating.

Check e.g. [Boost Score](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents) OR If you are using Dismax parser check for parameter [Boost Query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29)

For your condition you can try `bq=ProductRating^2.0`

You should probably use the combination of boost on the product name and product type to get proper results with a different weightage to account for the search else as in your case its just a Sort as replied by @Arun